# using dpdk example gives the error port is not enabled in port mask

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to integrate the my custom application with DPDK examples using modified Makefile

1. Basic forwarding application (l2fwd and skeleton) with custom application code and Makefile works without issue.
2. L3fwd ACL application with custom application code and Makefile fails to identify the NIC ports

Error Log: `port is not enabled in port mask`
NIC: Mellanox PMD

Custom Makefile:

```
    link_directories(/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/)
    include_directories(/usr/local/include/)
    link_directories(/opt/mellanox/dpdk/lib)
    
    SET(DPDK_LIBS "-Wl,--whole-archive  -l dpdk  -Wl,--no-whole-archive")
    add_executable( exAppln exAppln.c )
    target_link_libraries(exAppln LINK_PUBLIC  pcap ${DPDK_LIBS} )
```

Argument passed for custom application is `./Sample -l 1,2 -n 4 -- -p 0x3 --config="(0,0,1)" --rule_ipv4="/root/rule_ipv4.db" --rule_ipv6=/root/rule_ipv6.db`

[EDIT-1] based on the conversation through comment

1. NIC is identified as Mellanox, but type mlx5 or mlx6 is not
2. Based on Makefile argument, it is shared library linking.
3. The command line arguments are not modified to intake PCIe probe for shared library PMD for mellanox
4. there are no log capture for `makefile` and  `--log-level` for the application.

Comment: please update the DPDK version in use? is your custom application using DPDK Makefile or using custom makefile?

Comment: I am using custom makefile.Have two versions of DPDK installed in system 20.11 and 19.05. In the cmakefile of custom application I have linked to two versions of dpdk as some so files were missing in recent version.

Comment: @imo please update the question with custom makefile and nic PMD in use for clarity

Comment: requested information on NIC PMD, but you have shared kernel interface name. This is not helpful. But based on the link args in makefile the issue is identified and solution is provided as answer, please accept or upvote to close the issue.

Comment: still waiting from your end to shared an update on running with option `-d`, identifying whether it is mellanox 5 or mellanox 6 NIC in use, as mentioned default makefile links statically (one can cross check based on the make logs)., requested to build the sample DPDK application with same flags to cross check

Comment: @Vipin I am using Mellanox 5 gdb ./Sample  -d librte_pmd_i40e.so -l 1,2 -n 4 -- -p 0x3 --config="(0,0,1)" --rule_ipv4="/root/rule_ipv4.db" --rule_ipv6=/root/rule_ipv6.db EAL error  port 0 is not enabled in port mask

Comment: you are still not passing the shared library associated to mellanox. the option `-d librte_pmd_i40e.so` is for Intel FVl.

Comment: please use `librte_pmd_mlx5.so` for mlx5 NIC

Comment: is there an update from your end after using right PMD driver? Let me know if you would like to have debug on the same.

Comment: Modifications in custom application  solved the error

Comment: thanks for the update, accept and upvote to close the question (as the steps shared in the answers helps to run in shared library mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK libraries can be linked statically or shared mode. Based on the update `-Wl,--whole-archive  -l dpdk  -Wl,--no-whole-archive` current linking is done in shared mode.

To enable probing of desired PMD use DPDK rte_eal_inti args `-d`. Example

1. for Fortville NIC use `-d librte_pmd_i40e.so`
2. for 82599ES use `-d librte_pmd_ixgbe.so`
3. [edit-1 based on the comment update] for mellanox net_mlx5 please use `-d librte_pmd_mlx5.so`.

note:

1. make sure to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/` is set which has the path to desired DPDK PMD.
2. if linking with statically libraries can be done, you can avoid passing option `-d`

Comment: Using Mellanox NIC and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to /opt/mellanox/dpdk/lib .Seems like the issue is different here.Initially I was using basic forwarding sample application and the integrated code was running without error as i wanted to use packet filtering i switched to l3fwd acl code

Comment: @ima if you need mellanox libraries also you should set your path to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu:/opt/mellanox/dpdk/lib`. have you passed the mellanox pmd with option `-d` for rte_eal_init? Does your mellanox NIC work with DPDK/example/l3fwd built with shared library mode (manually build the application)?